# how to crawl web pages fast when the number of connection is limited

Tags: python, http, network-programming

I wrote a web crawler to crawl product infomation from www.amazon.com by using **urllib2**,but it seems that amazon limit the connection for each IP to 1.

When I start more than one thread to crawl simultaneously, it raises `HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable`.
I want to start more threads to crawl fast,so how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Short version: you can't, and it would be a bad idea to even try.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably switch to use the Amazon API for product queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use python [requests](http://python-requests.org/) module to make connection through proxy IPs . The code will look like

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "<an HTTP proxy IP>",
  "https": "<an HTTPS proxy IP>"
}
response = requests.get("http://your_url.com", proxies=proxies)
```

You should be able to get HTTP and HTTPS proxy ips from [here](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/) 
See [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) for more help